# Express.js res.render's second parameter and passing data to views

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am going through various tutorials on node.js and express and cannot find what this particular part of the code is actually doing. It's for the second parameter of `res.render` below. The part I am unsure of is the `mascots: mascots` part. Is this declaring a mascots variable? I cannot find anywhere in the javascript language where this is done like this so it's confusing me as to where they got this. Of course, I am just starting to learn Javascript so it could be somewhere obvious but haven't found it yet. It looks like it's an object (b/c of the curly braces `{}`) but even if it is, the value of named mascots is not clear to me. Is this the `array` of `objects` they are referring to? And if so it's still very confusing to me. I could get an answer for it after searching a good bit so asking here.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var mascots = [
        {name: 'Sammy', organization: 'DigitalOcean', birth_year: 2012},
        {name: 'Tux', organization: 'Linux', birth_year: 1996},
        {name: 'Moby Dick', organization: 'Docker', birth_year: 2013},
    ];
    var tagline = "No programming concept is complete without a cute animal mascot";
    
    res.render('pages/index', {
        mascots: mascots, // this line and the one below is what I am not understanding
        tagline: tagline
    });
});
```

This particular tutorial is located here for reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application Nice introduction and I understand everything except these two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    res.render('pages/index', {
        mascots: mascots,
        tagline: tagline
    });
```

this part passes down the `mascots` array and the `tagline` string to your view `pages/index` and then you can access both of them from your view.
I think what's confusing you is the naming. It doesn't necessarily have to be the same name.
For example if I name it like

```js
    res.render('pages/index', {
        myMascotsArray: mascots,
        myTagline: tagline
    });
```

you can access the `mascots` array you defined as `myMascotsArray` from your view.
Referring the link you mentioned they have used EJS as the templating engine where you can write javascript between the `<%` `%>` tags.
Here you can notice that `mascots` array is accessed in the form of `myMascotsArray` from the view.

```js
    <ul>
      <% myMascotsArray.forEach(function(mascot) { %>
        <li>
          <strong><%= mascot.name %></strong>
          representing <%= mascot.organization %>,
          born <%= mascot.birth_year %>
        </li>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes! The naming was the main part of my confusion so that clears up almost everything right there. Thank you! What exactly is `myMascotsArray`? Is this an Express specific type of thing as I haven't seen this done in Javascript yet. I keep thinking in terms of declaring a type of variable. of type array. Is this like declaring a variable of type mascots (array) named `myMascotsArray`? Regardless, this clears up my confusion and I can work through the rest and understand things much better.

Comment: yeah it is an express specific thing. what the docs say about the second parameter of res.render is  'an object whose properties define local variables for the view.'

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.render

Comment: Thank you so much for your help *and* patience :). That clears up everything.